# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/caffe/build/tools/caffe': '/opt/caffe/build/tools/caffe'

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, caffe, pycaffe

I installed caffe-cpu on my Ubuntu v18 VM via the apt install command. I am struggling to figure out where the install directory is located, correct me if I'm wrong but I believe there is not a install directory. My NN model I'm trying to execute requires the path of build tools from caffe. How can I obtain this? I have not seen any information about this anywhere.

```
INFO 2018-08-04 09:41:40: Setting up mAlexNet trained on PKLot_train, validated on PKLot_val, CNRPark-EXT_val, tested on PKLot_test_CNRPark-EXT_test ...
sh: 1: /opt/caffe/python/draw_net.py: not found
INFO 2018-08-04 09:41:40: Training on PKLot_train while validating on PKLot_val, CNRPark-EXT_val ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 99, in <module>
    exp.run(plot=False) # run without live plot
  File "/home/sarim/Desktop/deep-parking/pyffe/experiment.py", line 42, in decorator
    return function(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sarim/Desktop/deep-parking/pyffe/experiment.py", line 399, in run
    caffe = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/opt/caffe/build/tools/caffe': '/opt/caffe/build/tools/caffe'
```

Comment: `dpkg-query -L caffe-cpu` will tell you where the package `apt` installed put its files. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/32507/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-installed-files-from-a-package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Ubuntu packages for `caffe` install the `caffe` executable in `/usr/bin`. The particular file you want is in `caffe-tools-cpu`, not `caffe-cpu` as such.

From https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/amd64/caffe-tools-cpu/filelist:

```
/usr/bin/caffe
/usr/bin/classification
/usr/bin/compute_image_mean
/usr/bin/convert_cifar_data
/usr/bin/convert_imageset
/usr/bin/convert_mnist_data
/usr/bin/convert_mnist_siamese_data
/usr/bin/extract_features
/usr/bin/upgrade_net_proto_binary
/usr/bin/upgrade_net_proto_text
/usr/bin/upgrade_solver_proto_text
/usr/share/bash-completion/completions/caffe
/usr/share/doc/caffe-tools-cpu/changelog.Debian.gz
/usr/share/doc/caffe-tools-cpu/copyright
/usr/share/lintian/overrides/caffe-tools-cpu
/usr/share/man/man1/caffe.1.gz
```